# Send a HTTP post request to an api in ruby

Tags: ruby, http-post

I am trying to send a post request to an other application in my local, using `after_create` callback in my model file.

Receiving error as #< Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>

```
require 'net/http'
def request_details
uri = URI('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/requests/new')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
req.body = {data1: self.data1, data2: self.data2,data3: self.data3,data4: self.data4}.to_json
response = http.request(req)
end
```

While I am getting this on the other application's log:

`Started POST "/api/v1/requests/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-29 01:20:43 +0530`

`SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC`

Can anyone figure the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem.

#### Installation

```
gem install rest-client
```

#### Usage

```
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.post(url, payload, headers={})
```

#### Example

```
# with params
RestClient.post(
  'http://example.com/resource', 
  {param1: 'one', nested: {param2: 'two'}}
)

# with params and headers 
RestClient.post(
  "http://example.com/resource", 
  {'x' => 1}.to_json,
  {content_type: :json, accept: :json}
)
```